# CMake toolchain file for custom toolchain (-c compiler option different meaning)

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, infineon

I try to create CMake toolchain file for Tasking Aurix compiler (ctc) in which `-c` option have different meaning:

```
-c --iso=<year>                    ISO C standard (90, 99) (default: 99)
```

Is it possible to omit `-c` parameter for object files recipes or maybe it's possible to set custom template for such recipes?

Currently I have ugly workaround for it so after CMake I call script which edit generated makefile's and change option `-c` to `-c 99` but preferably I would like to be able to generate valid makefile's from CMake directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I was able to find solution. To achieve it I had to overwrite default behavior by setting   `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILE_OBJECT` variable,  so in my case bellow lines

```
set(target_compiler ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-c 99")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT "${target_compiler} <INCLUDES> <FLAGS> -o <OBJECT> <SOURCE>")
```

solved my problem